# GRUB command line appears on boot after deleting Ubuntu partition from Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I dual booted Win 10 and Ubuntu, then I deleted my Ubuntu partition. But every time I start my PC I see

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. 
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. 
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions".
```

I can run windows by exiting from there and choosing windows boot loader.

How can I stop this screen from appearing and delete GRUB?

Comment: Above is correct if a BIOS install. If UEFI, you should in UEFI be able to change boot order. Or directly boot Windows from UEFI one time boot menu often f10 or f12 check manual. See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EasyUEFI` http://easyuefi.com to delete the Ubuntu option from boot menu http://www.easyuefi.com/faq/en_US/Delete-UEFI-Boot-Entries.html

This will remove the Ubuntu boot option. To remove the grub files follow these instructions:

http://www.easyuefi.com/faq/en_US/Rebuild-EFI-System-Partition.html

Answer (score -1):

Try Using windows bootable DVD

- In rescue mode reach the command prompt
- type `fixmbr (device-name)` e.g.`\Device\HardDisk0` or just execute `fixmbr` without any argument or
- you can do  `bootrec /fixboot and bootrec /fixmbr`

you'll get windows boot back